# iOS - is enabling microphone required for an app to run in background

Tags: ios, background, microphone

Had a question from a user of an iPhone 4s  model MF260LL/A version 7.0.4.  User is a driver for Uber, who supplied the phone.  She just got a notice instructing her "Make sure and update to the latest version and enable the microphone to be able to run the app in the background "

Question is enabling the microphone required as a condition to run an app in the background?  If so why?

She was suspicious about the microphone part.  It sounds fishy to me, but I told her I'd check and get back to her.

Thanks

Comment: Audio (both playing & recording audio) is one of several iOS background modes, so if an app wants to run in the background, it could potentially record audio just to keep active.  But I personally wouldn't trust an app that requests to record audio for no reason... What tasks do you think this particular app needs to run in the background?  Is it the Uber app?

Comment: Don't have a real answer, but the only app the phone runs is the Uber app.  Phone is configured by Uber so user can't make calls, access the internet, no bluetooth, etc.